# Type Initializer Error in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

My WPF application was compiling fine

but after I added a Label element,

```
<Label Content="Time Remaining:" Foreground="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

it shows

> The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily' threw an
>   exception

on compilation. It works if I remove the Label element.

I searched for a while and tried using this line of code

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("windir", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"));
```

but still it shows the exception.

**EDIT:** I deleted all the fonts in my computer except the protected fonts and it solved the problem.

Comment: Post relevant XAML code here otherwise it will be a guessing problem.

Comment: Label is perfectly fine. There is something wrong in code behind file. Try posting code which replicates your issue.

Comment: @RohitVats i didnt write anything in the code-behind file. I just created a grid and added a label element in it.

Comment: It seems an issue in your machine then. Check out [here](http://veodin.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/123533-error-the-type-initializer-for-system-windows-med).

Comment: @RohitVats The error occurs only when i set some value to the Content of the label

Comment: Yeah it will come even if you try to set `Text` on your `TextBlock` because issue in FontFamily which is initialized when Text is rendered on screen.

Comment: @RohitVats i tried the solution given in those links. it didnt help, there are no invalid characters in my font regis.